# How to use logstash conditionals(if...in) correctly?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I had a problem about conditionals(especially about if...in) in logstash configuration.

When I used the logstash filter plugin "geoip" to generate location information by this config:

```
geoip {
  source => "ip_addr"
}
```

I found that some IP(for example: 63.149.98.170) could not generate "timezone" field in "geoip" field, result like this:

```
"geoip": {
  "ip": "63.149.98.170",
  "country_code2": "US",
  "country_code3": "USA",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "continent_code": "NA",
  "latitude": 38,
  "longitude": -97,
  "dma_code": 0,
  "area_code": 0,
  "location": [
    -97,
    38
  ]
}
```

"timezone" field is important for me to show a table view, so if it can not be generated, I'd like to create an empty one in order to see the incomplete data in Kibana table view.

So, I add a config after geoip config data like this:

```
if !([timezone] in [geoip]) {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "[geoip][timezone]" => "unknown"
    }
  }
}
```

But the results seemed unexpected. When other IPs was recognized by geoip filter and the "timezone" field was created normally, mutate still added "unknown" to "timezone" field. Result like this:

```
"geoip": {
  "ip": "125.69.76.30",
  "country_code2": "CN",
  "country_code3": "CHN",
  "country_name": "China",
  "continent_code": "AS",
  "region_name": "32",
  "city_name": "Chengdu",
  "latitude": 30.66669999999999,
  "longitude": 104.06670000000003,
  "timezone": [
    "Asia/Chongqing",
    "unknown"          <-----look at this, "unknown" append to timezone field
  ],
  "real_region_name": "Sichuan",
  "location": [
    104.06670000000003,
    30.66669999999999
  ]
}
```

but after I remove the "!" symbol

```
if ([timezone] in [geoip])
```

"unknown" was not appended to "timezone", in other words, the "if...in" condition was not jumped in.

So, what's the problem with my configuration? 
Thank you for everybody helping me!

The official logstash configuring link is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the `"[geoip][timezone]" => "unknown"` is added to all events.

Meaning there is a problem with the `if !([timezone] in [geoip])`. I think this check if the field `timezone` (not `geoip.timezone`) has the same value as the field `geoip`. So the `[timezone] in [geoip]` test always evaluate at false, so all events get the `"[geoip][timezone]" => "unknown"`.

To test if a field does not exist, according to the linked documentation, you can use:

```
if !([field])
```

> The expression if [foo] returns false when:
>
> - [foo] doesn’t exist in the event,

So in your case, you'll have to replace `if !([timezone] in [geoip])` with `if !([geoip][timezone])`

Comment: wow, that's true! I have tested both of conditions of IPs, all that passed!